# mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Tags: server, mysql

i cannot start my mysql server, it crashed all a sudden and i can not find any useful log to say why.

my disk has still some space left, several Gigabytes.

last logs from `journalctl -feu mysql` are like this, which doesnt help at all:

```
May 06 16:04:23 soy systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server... 
May 06 16:04:23 soy su[5927]: Successful su for mysql by root 
May 06 16:04:23 soy su[5927]: + ??? root:mysql 
May 06 16:04:23 soy su[5927]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user mysql by (uid=0) 
May 06 16:04:23 soy su[5927]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user mysql 
May 06 16:04:24 soy systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE 
May 06 16:04:24 soy systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. May 06 16:04:24 soy systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

mysql version 8
mysql  Ver 8.0.20 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
Linux soy 4.15.0-65-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 17 17:06:04 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
lsb_release -a
```

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

and here the service info:

```
service mysql status 

● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-05-06 16:04:24 UTC; 7min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html   Process: 5961 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)   Process: 5876 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 5961 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)    Status: "Server startup in progress"

May 06 16:04:23 soy systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server... 
May 06 16:04:23 soy su[5927]: Successful su for mysql by root 
May 06 16:04:23 soy su[5927]: + ??? root:mysql 
May 06 16:04:23 soy su[5927]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user mysql by (uid=0) 
May 06 16:04:23 soy su[5927]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user mysql 
May 06 16:04:24 soy systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE 
May 06 16:04:24 soy systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. 
May 06 16:04:24 soy systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

error log says filesystem is case insensitive. i have no idea how it could be relevant.
but it seems to be the problem, the mysql folder is "unusable"

> 020-05-07T07:55:44.761003Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) initializing of server in progress as
>   process 2024 2020-05-07T07:55:44.762802Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457]
>   [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in
>   it. Aborting. 2020-05-07T07:55:44.762827Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236]
>   [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable.
>   You can remove all files that the server added to it.
>   2020-05-07T07:55:44.762887Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
>   2020-05-07T07:55:44.762984Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community
>   Server - GPL. 2020-05-07T07:55:45.026958Z 0 [System] [MY-010116]
>   [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 2032
>   2020-05-07T07:55:45.041675Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to
>   find valid data directory. 2020-05-07T07:55:45.041828Z 0 [ERROR]
>   [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
>   2020-05-07T07:55:45.041889Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
>   2020-05-07T07:55:45.042277Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community
>   Server - GPL. 2020-05-07T07:55:45.298208Z 0 [System] [MY-010116]
>   [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 2040
>   2020-05-07T07:55:45.305008Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to
>   find valid data directory. 2020-05-07T07:55:45.305180Z 0 [ERROR]
>   [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
>   2020-05-07T07:55:45.305248Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
>   2020-05-07T07:55:45.305563Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community
>   Server - GPL.

Comment: Do you have anything interesting in your `/var/log/mysql/error.log`?

Comment: added error log, mysql wants to initialize, but there are all the databases already here.